# Splicing multiple LED lights

Tags: electrical, wiring, splicing

I've just built a TARDIS and I am about to wire up the lights for the windows, the sign boxes along the top, and the beacon light at the roof peak. I've bought and installed these three items:

- [LED rope](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NLZH57R) (4 of these)
- [LED strip](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Utilitech-96-in-Plug-In-Under-Cabinet-LED-Strip-Light/1000640209) (1 of these)
- [Beacon light](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-3-Watt-Oil-Rubbed-Bronze-Outdoor-Integrated-LED-Landscape-Path-Light-with-Frosted-Shade-JAQ1501L-2-Fros/301610338) (1 of these)

My next step is to connect these all to a rechargeable 12-volt SLA battery, then connect that battery to a solar panel. I would like to avoid a power strip, though, so my question is:

Can I splice all these six wires together into one lead that then runs into the battery?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, this is really an electronics question, and is off-topic here. You should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about electronics.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Tiny homes are on-topic.   "But a TARDIS is too small for a tiny home" ha ha, it could be a mansion inside...

Comment: @DanielGriscom I didn't even know there was a domain specific to electronics. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These are al 12v lights, and 12v is pretty safe to work with.  There should be nothing wrong with splicing all the positive wires and negative wires to one cable that then hooks up to the battery.

Because they are LED lights running on DC current, polarity matters, and it might not be obvious on the wires which is positive and which is negative so pay attention to that.